# How can I replace aeiou with bfjpv in Perl?

Tags: perl, string, transliteration

I want to replace aeiou with bfjpv in user inputted string. Here is the code which is not working :-

```
print "Enter any String :";
while(($string = <>) ne "\n"){

    @arr = split(//,$string);

    for($i = 0 ; $i < $#arr ; $i++){
        $char = $arr[$i];

        if($char eq 'a' || $char eq 'e' || $char eq 'i' || $char eq 'o' || $char eq 'u'){
            $char = $char + 1;
        }
        print $char;
    }

}
```

What should I do to add one character? I mean how do I replace `a` with `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$char = chr(ord($char) + 1);
```

ord = convert character to integer

chr = convert integer to character

Comment: Far too complex. $chr++ does the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but this is far clearer in meaning. What if chr was an integer?

Answer (score 10):

You can just do

```
$char++;
```

in place of

```
$char = $char + 1;
```

Also you really don't need to loop to do the replacement. Just use the [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) operator as:

```
($new_string = $string) =~ tr [aeiou] [bfjpv];
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$string =~ tr/aeiou/bfjpv/;
```

Does the whole job. See the [perlop manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2fSEARCHLIST%2fREPLACEMENTLIST%2fcds).